# Move migrations to the first page of the close dialog

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-dialog

With the new close system, voting to migrate now requires four steps:

1. Clicking the "close" link
2. Selecting "off-topic because..."
3. Selecting "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", and
4. Finally selecting the site.

How about we make the process a bit less tedious by eliminating the second step?

[image]

Other than one less click (yes, I'm that lazy), we'll probably also stop confusing people from [thinking they voted to migrate just because another site is mentioned in a predefined "off topic" reason](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/confusing-closing-off-topic-dialog).

Comment: Is four clicks really that tough? Or do you migrate so many questions the fourth click is just wearing your fingers out?

Comment: @Luke is four clicks necessary? There's enough real estate to support the migrate choice there. The only draw back I see is the potential for someone thinking "off-topic" and then going to off-topic where Migrate isn't a choice so a close vote happening instead. Solution being add migrate to both menus, but then that does kind of stink. Either way I'd rather see migrate on the main choice than off-topic, perhaps even above off-topic so people see it first (This would encourage migrations over closures which is a better way to gather good content than closure)

Comment: @Luke No, arthritis is wearing my fingers out. Nonsensical extra clicks don't help though.

Comment: I wouldn't call it nonsensical

Comment: @Luke Doesn't really matter what you'd call it. What's the point of having an extra click if we can avoid it?

Comment: Wouldn't you migrate because it was off-topic? It's more organized when you put it in the off-topic category.

Comment: It's also a lot more cluttered (especially with wordy predefined "off topic" reasons) and can be confusing (see linked Meta ProgSE questions).

Comment: The way you recommend would clutter the first page up a lot more. There would be six options (you cut out "primarily opinion-based" in your picture).

Comment: @Luke Lots of available space in the first page, and the headings help avoid clutter. In the off topic dialog, although it might seem there's space, there's not (it's used for expanding "other").