# Move migrate option in flag dialog to "this question doesn't belong here" submenu

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

I just realized that the migration option is buried under many levels in the flag dialog:

[image]

This takes many clicks to reach, and, besides, it's hard to find.

Why not keep it in the "this question doesn't belong here" menu (i.e. the "Closing" menu)?

For that matter, why not do the same for the VTC dialog?

Comment: Related / possible dupe: [Move migrations to the first page of the close dialog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186359/162704)

Comment: @Yannis Yeah, more or less a dupe. You may want to mention how deep down it gets buried in the flag dialog there.